# Not able to read data from url in Python

Tags: python, sockets, url, urlopen

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib import urlopen
import re

webpage = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)').read()

patFinderTitle = re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')
patFinderLink = re.compile('<link rel.*href="(.*)"/>')

findPatTitle = re.findall(PatFinderTitle,webpage)
findPatLink = re.findall(PatFinderLink,webpage)

listIterator = []
listIterator [:] = range(1,5)

for i in listIterator:
    print findPatTitle[i]
    print findpatLink[i]
    print "\n"
```

when i am running the above code i'm getting following errors:

```
 bash-3.2$ ./webscrapping.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./webscrapping.py", line 6, in ?
 webpage = urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)').read()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib.py", line 82, in urlopen
 return opener.open(url)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib.py", line 190, in open
 return getattr(self, name)(url)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/urllib.py", line 313, in open_http
 h.endheaders()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 798, in endheaders
 self._send_output()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 679, in _send_output
 self.send(msg)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 646, in send
 self.connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.4/httplib.py", line 614, in connect
 socket.SOCK_STREAM):
 IOError: [Errno socket error] (8, 'node name or service name not known')
```

I think my version of python supports urlopen module

```
bash-3.2$ python 
Python 2.4.6 (#1, Dec 13 2009, 23:45:11) [C] on sunos5            
>>> from urllib import urlopen 
>>>
```

it doesn't give me any error

what could be the reason for the errors? It's not syntactical error i think.
Any advice?

thanks :)

Comment: socket error means an error in resolving hostname. Btw use the requests module in python to access urls.

Comment: its working fine with python 2.7,try with latest version

Comment: i'm using Python 2.4.6, I cannot update the version on my server :(

Comment: @user3581172 Just out of curiosity. It's your server and you cannot update? Also 2.4.6 is quite old and many tools and libraries do not support it anymore. There were some important changes around 2.6/2.7 and the codes designed for them might not work in older versions, so an update would be strongly recommended.

Comment: what i meant by "my" was the server on which i am working on, it is not my personal server. I know it's old but it supports the urlopen module i think.

Comment: Can you ping `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)` from the server? Does it only fail when on the server?